While installing a add-in for Microsoft Project , it is prompting to download .Net Framework 4.8.1 though the client machine already has it
I have targeted my MS Project addin with .Net Framework 4.8.1 ( I installed the SDK and runtime in VS 2022) which has added BootStrapperPackage cml tag with 4.8.1 in .csproj file and I have build the client zip file
When I try to run .exe after extracting the zip it is prompting to download 4.8.1 setup again though it is already installed in machine , seems like it is not recognizing the 4.8.1 version that is already installed on windows.
Any idea how to fix this issue?
I want to exe should recognize 4.8.1 version installed on machine and if it is not present then only it should ask for installation.
